# replace the file in deployment target server using powershell script in azure devops pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

Replace the file in deployment target server using powershell script in azure devops pipeline on premise.
I'm using the below script and script is run fine without errors but file was not getting replaced. can anyone please help into it.

thank you all in advance.

Comment: So.. where is the _below script_?

Comment: Hi, How was it going with this case? Please add your powershell script.